# Python Pandas how to concatenate horizontally on the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm having issues with the formatting of a CSV I am trying to create. Here is the code I have so far

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import glob

usernamesDF=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\jotam\\Desktop\\Modeling Fanaticism\\User List\\users.csv') #CSV with list of users that posted in greatawakening subreddit
users=set(usernamesDF['author'].tolist()) # removes duplicates andconverts dataframe to list

botsDF=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\jotam\\Desktop\\Modeling Fanaticism\\User List\\Bot list.csv') #CSV with a list of bots
bots=set(botsDF['author'].tolist()) #removes any potential duplicates and converts dataframe to list

users=list(users.difference(bots)) #removes any known bots from user list

subreddits = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jotam\Desktop\Modeling Fanaticism\Focus Group\Top Subreddits\Top 500 Subreddits.csv') # creats dataframe of top 500 subreddits
subreddits = (subreddits['subreddit'].tolist())[0:99] #converts to list and slices first 100

dfList = []



for user in users[:1]:
    print(user)
    
    for subreddit in subreddits:
        path = (r"C:\\Users\\jotam\\Desktop\\Modeling Fanaticism\\Focus Group\\Subreddit CSVs\\" + str(subreddit) + '.csv')
        
        if os.path.exists(path): #checks if the csv for each subreddit exists in folder
            print(subreddit)
            df = pd.read_csv(path,index_col = False
                             )
            df = df.loc[df['author'] == user] #locates within the subreddit csv the current user in the for loop iteration
            
            if len(df.index) == 0: #if user has not posted in the subreddit creates the empty dataframe into a useable one since its needed for the model
                if_empty = {'author': user, 'subreddit' : subreddit, 'post_count' : '0' , 'total_score': '0', 'times_gilded' : '0', 'has_flair' : '0', 'is_distinguished' : '0'}
                df = pd.DataFrame(data=if_empty,index = [0],columns=['author','subreddit','post_count','total_score','times_gilded','has_flair','is_distinguished'])
            
            dfList.append(df)
    concatDF = pd.concat(dfList,axis=1,ignore_index = False) #concatenates horizontally
    # concatDF= concatDF.groupby(by='author')
    
concatDF.to_csv(r'C:\Users\jotam\Desktop\Modeling Fanaticism\Focus Group\NEWCONCAT.csv',index = False)
```

[This image is the goal of what I am trying to make with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAXSO.png)

[This image is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zumMk.png)

For contaxt I am trying to concatenate horixzontally since the way it is in picture 1 every 5 columns after the 1st author column corresponds to a specific subreddit in the same order as a list I have from most posted to least posted subreddit. What I currently have I'm trying have each row corresponding to 1 user although in the 2nd image It's breaking it up into 4 rows. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [mre] especially for this question. Your goal output is incredibly large: can you break this down into a very small subset of the result that you'd like to see? On top of that, while reading CSV's might work fine on your computer, we have no access to that data here (and in almost every situation, we don't want it; just the smallest subset that illustrates your problem and desired solution).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).